# Downloading s3objects with a save as dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I am using Amazon SDK. In my ASP.NET application,  I am trying to directly stream an S3Object to a client, without loading it via my web server and then sending it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use something like silverlight on the client to make the call to Amazon's S3 directly without going through your web server. The only thing you'll need to look out for is the cross-domain restrictions, but fortunately S3 allows this. There's a good post on setting this up here:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/05/access-amazon-s3-services-with-silverlight-2.aspx